# How do I know if I installed latest version?

Tags: drush, upgrading

I am trying to create a cron script which uses Drush, and that does the following (using pseudo-code).

```
if([My Drupal core version] < [The last core version]) {
    [Backup DB]
    [Put the site into maintenance mode]
    [Upgrade core]
    [Remove the site from maintenance mode]
}
```

I don't know, how to implement `[My Drupal core version] < [The last core version]`.

How do I check if the site is using the latest version of Drupal?

Comment: It would be interesting, but what if something goes wrong with the updating process... I don't know, a new requirement, something is broken in the website, the server suddenly shuts down in the middle of the process... anything. I personally prefer to manually execute my updates to be able to fix anything in case there is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `drush pm-updatestatus drupal` and see if you get any results.

Answer (score 1):

See [update_get_available](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21update%21update.module/function/update_get_available/7.x) function. It returns available list updates, including core.